# Wordpress version issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a `Wordpress 4.5.4` website I downloaded from a `remote server` to my `local development server` installing both, the files and the database.

On the `remote server` is working "apparently OK" but on my `local server` is doing something strange because on lot of files is doing the following appending:

```
http://<domain>.com/wp-content/themes/mytemplate/style.css?ver=1.8.4
```

Notice the version at the end: `1.8.4` while the current version is: `4.5.4`
(this situation happens with lot of files)

Then I checked on the server and for these files the version at the end is the right one: `4.5.4`

Then on both, on the `remote server` and on the `local development server` I read the global variable: `$wp_version` and on both cases I got the right version: `4.5.4`, so I don't know why the `1.8.4` at the end as default version for those files on my `local development server`?

On my `local development server` the website looks really different than on the remote server and the files I download as well as the database is the right one, because on the root of the remote directory I put a dummy file and I can read it via the browser using the url. Also, I tried changing the database password on the `wp-config.php` file on the server and I got database connection error, so the files I downloaded and the database are the right ones.

Any idea on how to solve this?

**EDIT 1**

```
Remote server: CentOS release 6.8 / PHP v5.3.24 / MySql v14.14
Local Dev server: Windows 7 / Wamp64 / PHP v7.0.0 / MySql v14.14
```

**EDIT 2**

On the local development server I modified the .htaccess file and the Windows' hosts file to use the same domain and avoid the necessity of these kind of changes (and be totally transparent for browsers). I do this with tons of websites, so for me is a normal procedure. Then my problem is not a localhost/domain.com conflict.

Comment: how are you running the site locally?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the website from the remote server to my local development server (files & database)

Comment: `local development server` - which is? mamp? wamp? linux vm?

Comment: I added this in formation to my post under "Edit 1"

Comment: `1.8.4` is likely the version of the *template*, not WordPress. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145141/attributing-a-version-number-to-a-child-themes-main-stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

The version add in a `wp_enqueue_script()` or `wp_enqueue_style()` is an optional value, and is related to the script version.

This value could be add the developper for caching purpose but it is not always corresponding to the WordPress version. The example you show is only relative to the theme and it's certainly hardcoded by the developper (this could be great to show us the wp_enqueue_style() ).

If version is set to false, a version number is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. But, some script can check and enqueue different file (I think about for minify css that will not load when you are enqueuing file locally).

In case, verify that both server show the same

```
get_bloginfo('version');
```

If not, change your local value with phpmyAdmin.

Hope it gives you some hints.

Answer (score -1):

You need to manually update the **siteurl** and **home** options in the  _options  table and replace  your domain with something like  http://localhost, and remember to **add the port number if you are running it at a different port than the usual  80**

Comment: This is not my problem because I modified the .htaccess file and the Windows' hosts file to use the same domain and avoid the necessity of these kind of changes. I do this with tons of websites, so for me is a normal procedure. This is discarded. Maybe I could start by figuring out why the 1.8.4 version added to the end of those files when it supposed to be: 4.5.4